# Using Xpath to retrieve HTML table

Tags: php, html, xpath

From [this url](http://www.betonews.com/table.asp?tp=2001&lang=en&dd=28&dm=7&dy=2014&df=1&dw=3), i want to perceive the HTML table and in particular, this element:

```
<td class="tbl_black_n_1" nowrap="">
<a href="popup.asp?tp=2100&amp;lang=en&amp;idm=553759" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.betonews.com//img/i_betfair.gif" width="12" height="10" border="0" alt=""></a>
<a href="popup.asp?tp=2110&amp;lang=en&amp;idm=553759" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.betonews.com//img/i_history.gif" width="12" height="10" border="0" alt=""></a>
</td>
```

There are more than one hundred `<tr>` structured at the same way, which contain lots of `<td>` I manage to loop with xpath to store all data in a database except one: the last `<td>` element.. i want the "href" attribute of the first `<a>`. So, in my example:

"popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=553759"

but when i run my query, id variable retrieve a NULL value. Help!!

This is my php code, but I can not go on..

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.betonews.com/table.asp?tp=2001&lang=en&dd=28&dm=7&dy=2014&df=1&dw=3';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($response);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$expression = '(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]';
$rows = $xpath->query($expression);

results = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $result = array();
  $td = $row->childNodes;
  $id = $td->item(36)->childNodes->item(1)->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue‌​;
  $result["id"] = $id;
  $results[] = $result;
  }
  var_dump($results);
```

@LarsH i use this php code to retrieve what you'have asked, the result is NULL

```
$expression = '(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]';
$rows = $xpath->query($expression);

$results = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $td = $row->childNodes;
  $ok = $td->item(36)->childNodes->item(1)->nodetype;
  echo $ok;


}
```

This is the value of `$row`, using your last expression suggested!

```
{  
   [  
      0
   ]   => array(1)   {  
      [  
         "ok"
      ]      => object(DOMAttr)#3 (21)      {  
         [  
            "name"
         ]         => string(4) "href"         [  
            "specified"
         ]         => bool(true)         [  
            "value"
         ]         => string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=556296"         [  
            "ownerElement"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "schemaTypeInfo"
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "nodeName"
         ]         => string(4) "href"         [  
            "nodeValue"
         ]         => string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=556296"         [  
            "nodeType"
         ]         => int(2)         [  
            "parentNode"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "childNodes"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "firstChild"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "lastChild"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "previousSibling"
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "nextSibling"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "attributes"
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "ownerDocument"
         ]         => string(22) "(object value omitted)"         [  
            "namespaceURI"
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "prefix"
         ]         => string(0) ""         [  
            "localName"
         ]         => string(4) "href"         [  
            "baseURI"
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "textContent"
         ]         => string(36) "popup.asp?tp=2100&lang=en&idm=556296"
      }
   }
```

Wow! We are able to see my value! So.. how to definitely retrieve it!? Thanks

Edit: Yeesss! I finally get it! I use `$id = $row->value;`! Thanks Thanks @LarsH

Comment: Could you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry.. It's now ok?

Comment: At this point I would suggest just putting in a lot of debugging statements, to find out what the value is at every step. What is the value of `$row`? of `$row->childNodes`? of `$td->item(36)`? etc. Tell us where it becomes null.

Comment: i edit my question! Maybe we are near the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that the first child node of the `<td>` is actually a text node, consisting of only white space. You could test that hypothesis by checking the [nodetype](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodetype):

```
$td->item(36)->childNodes->item(1)->nodetype
```

To fix the problem, you could try more of the navigation in XPath, e.g.

```
(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]/td[36]/a[1]/@href
```

and then loop through those results:

```
$expression = '(//table[@cellpadding="3"])[1]/tr[position() > 1]/td[19]/a[1]/@href';
$ids = $xpath->query($expression);

results = array();

foreach ($ids as $idNode) {
  $result = array();
  $result["id"] = $idNode->nodeValue;
  $results[] = $result;
}
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer LarsH, so.. after i add this query, how i can get my "id" value? Can you give me an example..? I tried in my loop:

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe: I added some code to my answer. Disclaimer: I know XPath, not PHP.

Comment: Nothing... it still returns NULL :(

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe: What was the nodetype of the first child node?

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe: I edited my answer to change `td[36]` to `td[19]`. I guess 36 was counting all child nodes, while 19 is counting only child `<td>` elements.